# Deploying MEAN.io Applications

Tags: mean.io

Never used MEAN.io, but it sounds very good.

Has anyone used it recently and found any major issues?

In terms of deploying the final application, is it like deploying any other Node / Mongo app?

Or do you need some MEAN CLI tools installed on the server as well? I'll be deploying to AWS with EB and using Compose.io for the hosted mongo server.

I'll also run it locally with vagrant / ansible to set up a local dev environment, any issues / gotchas that I should be aware of?

Going to spin up a test server tomorrow, just wanted to see if people have had success in production with this framework.